# How to exclude fields from being indexed in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to utilize ElasticSearch to store large sets of data. Most of the data will be searchable, however, there are some field that will be there just so the data is stored and returned upon request.

Here is my mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "amenities": {
        "type": "completion"
      },
      "summary": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "street_number": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "street_name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "street_suffix": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "city": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "raw": { 
            "type":  "keyword"
          }
      },
      "state_or_province": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "postal_code": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "mlsid": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "source_id": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "subtype": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "year_built": {
        "type": "short"
      },
      "community": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "elementary_school": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "middle_school": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "jr_high_school": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "high_school": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "area_size": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "lot_size": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "bathrooms": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "bedrooms": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "listed_at": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "price": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "sold_at": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "sold_for": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "total_photos": {
        "type": "short"
      },
      "formatted_addressLine": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "formatted_address": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "price_changes": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "fields": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "deleted_at": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "is_available": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "is_unable_to_find_coordinates": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "source": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `fields` and `price_changes` properties are there in case the user want to read that info. But that info should not be searchable or indexed. The `fields` holds a large list of `key-value` pairs whereas `price_changes` fields hold multiple objects of the same type.

Currently, when I attempt to bulk create records, I get `Limit of total fields [1000] has been exceeded` error. I am guessing this error is happening because every key-value pair in the `fields` collection is considered a field in elasticsearch.

How can I store the `fields` and the `price_changes` object as non-searchable data and not index it or count it toward the fields count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the enabled property at field level to store the fields without indexing them.
Read here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html

```
  "price_changes": { 
    "type": "object",
    "enabled": false
  }
```

NOTE: Are you able to create an index using the mapping you gave in the question? It gives me syntax errors(Duplicate key) at "type" field. I think you are missing a closing bracket for "city" field.